# print only barcode size with iframe

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to print barcode with size(7cm * 1.3cm). But it is printed as A4 page size as shown image1.
My code is

```
let printFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
let printableElement = document.getElementById("papa");
printFrame.setAttribute("id", "printjs");
printFrame.srcdoc = "<div>" + printableElement.outerHTML + "</div>";
document.body.appendChild(printFrame);
document.getElementById("printjs").contentWindow.print();
```

How can I do to print the wanted size as image2.
Can anyone help me?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, the code seems to be about 7cm on the A4 page. If this is not the expected result, can you provide an image with the expected one?

Comment: Btw. it would help, if you would take the time and format the code, to make it easier to read for those you expect help from.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to scale the total width of the document down?

You can scale it with css. 7cm is a third of DIN A4s width

```html
<div id="papa" style="transform: scale(.3333);transform-origin: left top;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB9WL.png" alt="your printable barcode" /></div>
```